# PHP 5.5.9 on OpenShift

Tags: php, drupal, openshift

I want to run my Drupal 8 application on the free OpenShift cloud. I had done this before with Drupal 7 and it worked fine but now i'm running into trouble with my version of PHP. Drupal 8 required PHP version 5.5.9 and OpenShift only offers version 5.4 by default. Is there a way to run php 5.5.9 on my openshift server or am i out of luck?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To run php 5.5.9 on OpenShift you would have to compile it on a compatible system (RHEL 6 or CENTOS 6) and then build your own custom cartridge for it using the [Cartridge Developers Guide](https://docs.openshift.org/origin-m4/oo_cartridge_developers_guide.html).  You could probably use an openshift gear to compile it, I would recommend a medium or large gear for that.